# Error al momento de instalar pods para ios

Tags: cocoapods

Estoy compilando una aplicación de quasar en modo capacitor, necesito utilizar push notifications por lo que requiere firebase, sin embargo, ya sea al momento de compilar o de instalar los pods, recibo el siguiente mensaje

```
[!] Error installing FirebaseCore
        [!] /usr/bin/git clone https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk.git
        /var/folders/lb/_qw1jzyx4x591brsxfvqssyr0000gn/T/d20231122-25516-znczdh --template=
        --single-branch --depth 1 --branch CocoaPods-10.18.0
        
        Cloning into
        '/var/folders/lb/_qw1jzyx4x591brsxfvqssyr0000gn/T/d20231122-25516-znczdh'...
        warning: Could not find remote branch CocoaPods-10.18.0 to clone.
        fatal: Remote branch CocoaPods-10.18.0 not found in upstream origin
```

He tratado de descargar los repositorios de cada pod y colocarles la ruta en el podfile, pero al momento de solucionarse el anterior continua uno nuevo.